# Cannot find source of quote

Tags: quotes

I have a quote in my commonplace book attributed to Aristotle but I cannot find the source. Googling the quote verbatim or substrings of it has not turned up neither the quote itself nor any variation thereof.

I was hoping to get some help, maybe someone else has come across the same quote and where and who actually said it.

The quote is,

> Wear the mask of a good man long enough and you become that good man

Comment: Yeah but that's a different quote

Comment: I found a source possibly, Object thinking. It's a book, and on page 163 it has the quote attributed to Aristotle as well but no sources to look to. That's all I could find.

Comment: That's the one! I have that book in my bookshelf, but I would have never considered going through it as it seemed to me as an unviable and unlikely candidate. Aristotle is not even in the index! Thanks @EvanM
Post it as an answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a source possibly, Object thinking. It's a book, and on page 163 it has the quote attributed to Aristotle as well but no sources to look to. That's all I could find.